# Generate Fields Dynamically

Tags: apex

I have a requirement for a form that will live in an LWC. One of the requirements is for a running list of questions. Rather than hard code a certain number of text fields into Salesforce I would like for the form to create a new row and a new field in Salesforce every time the user adds a row.

If the form begins with 5 rows and the user completes one and saves the record there will now be 6 rows.

From my reading, I am assuming I will need to call the Metadata API each time to this.

I am hoping someone can give me an idea of the effort involved in this solution?

Comment: Most users don't have permission to call the Metadata API. What about storing form and response details as JSON?

Comment: David  I have never done that. Can you tell me how it would work or point me to the documentation?

Comment: More of a general suggestion than a concrete solution. You can use Long Text fields to store JSON, and this can sometimes be exploited to simulate the effect of having a more flexible schema by building your UI dynamically based on a JSON definition.

Comment: Typically, a developer would create a new type of record. The user would then be editing a list of records. This generally provides the best set of features (reporting, search capabilities, etc). Imagine if you were to create a new set of contact fields on an Account record each time you wanted to add a contact to an account. That would be impractical at best.

Comment: Also, see the concept of ["first normal form"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), which says we should strive to not duplicate data in a database by adding more tables. The same concept applies to Salesforce as well.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox can you give a me any more detail on creating a new type of record. If I am following something like 1. Create a Custom Object Questions__c.  The object has the required fields and each time the user completes on we just create a new Questions__c?

Comment: @BrooksJohnson Yep, that's the general idea. You might want a parent object to link the questions together (or not, I don't know your intent). For example, you might have a Survey__c object with Question__c as a set of child records.